# Listview button click throws null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception, adapter

Inside my `UpdateSupervitionActivity` class `CallAdapter()` method is called to generate the `listview`. The `listview` has a button for each `item` to remove an `item`. After the `listview` is loaded, when I try to remove an item from the `listview` by clicking the listview button, it throws a `nullpointer` exception and the app crashes.

**Java class with CallAdapter() method**:

```
package bd.edu.bubt.regup;

public class UpdateSupervitionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText fac_code, s_intake, s_section;
ListView listView;
Button search, addlist, update;
Spinner shift;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_supervition);

    fac_code = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sh_code);
    s_intake = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.intake);
    s_section = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.section);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.faclistview);
    shift = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.shift);
    addlist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addlist);
    search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
    update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);
}

public void CallAdapter(Context context)
    {
        adapterlist.clear();

        if(daylist.size() == 0)
        {
            //no intake list for day shift

            if(evelist.size() == 0)
            {
                //no intake list for evening shift
            }
            else if(evelist.size() > 0)
            {
                for (int i=0;i<evelist.size();i++)
                {
                    String s = evelist.get(i);
                    int p = s.indexOf("-");

                    String intake = s.substring(0,p);
                    String section = s.substring(p+1,s.length());

                    adapterlist.add(new UpdateSupervisionItem(intake, section, "Evening"));
                }
            }
        }
        else if(daylist.size() > 0)
        {
            for (int i=0;i<daylist.size();i++)
            {
                String s = daylist.get(i);
                int p = s.indexOf("-");

                String intake = s.substring(0,p);
                String section = s.substring(p+1,s.length());

                adapterlist.add(new UpdateSupervisionItem(intake, section, "Day"));
            }

            if(evelist.size() == 0)
            {
                //no intake list for evening shift
            }
            else if(evelist.size() > 0)
            {
                for (int i=0;i<evelist.size();i++)
                {
                    String s = evelist.get(i);
                    int p = s.indexOf("-");

                    String intake = s.substring(0,p);
                    String section = s.substring(p+1,s.length());

                    adapterlist.add(new UpdateSupervisionItem(intake, section, "Evening"));
                }
            }
        }

        UpdateSupervisionAdapter updateSupervisionAdapter = new UpdateSupervisionAdapter(context, R.layout.update_supervision_list_view_layout, adapterlist);
        listView.setAdapter(updateSupervisionAdapter);
    }
}
```

**Adapter class:**

```
package bd.edu.bubt.regup;

public class UpdateSupervisionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UpdateSupervisionItem> {

    ArrayList<UpdateSupervisionItem> adapterlist = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;

    public UpdateSupervisionAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<UpdateSupervisionItem> objects) {

        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
        adapterlist = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return super.getCount();
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_supervision_list_view_layout, null);

        TextView intake = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.intake);
        TextView section = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.section);
        TextView shift = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.shift);
        final Button remove = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.remove);

        remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.blink_anim);
                remove.startAnimation(animation);

                UpdateSupervisionItem updateSupervisionItem = getItem(position);

                String in_take = updateSupervisionItem.getIntake();
                String sec_tion = updateSupervisionItem.getSection();
                String shi_ft = updateSupervisionItem.getShift();

                UpdateSupervitionActivity updateSupervitionActivity = new UpdateSupervitionActivity();

                if(TextUtils.equals(shi_ft,"Day"))
                {
                    updateSupervitionActivity.daylist.remove(in_take+ "-" +sec_tion);
                    updateSupervitionActivity.CallAdapter(context);
                }
                else if(TextUtils.equals(shi_ft,"Evening"))
                {
                    updateSupervitionActivity.evelist.remove(in_take+ "-" +sec_tion);
                    updateSupervitionActivity.CallAdapter(context);
                }
            }
        });

        intake.setText("Intake: " +adapterlist.get(position).getIntake());
        section.setText("Section: " +adapterlist.get(position).getSection());
        shift.setText("Shift: " +adapterlist.get(position).getShift());

        return v;
    }

}
```

**Error log:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: bd.edu.bubt.regup, PID: 31219
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                      at bd.edu.bubt.regup.UpdateSupervitionActivity.CallAdapter(UpdateSupervitionActivity.java:352)
                      at bd.edu.bubt.regup.UpdateSupervisionAdapter$1.onClick(UpdateSupervisionAdapter.java:70)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Could you show the part where you initialize `listView`??

Comment: @Ikazuchi ok I have added that code in my class activity part. You can check.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Instead of using ListView, use RecyclerView for dealing with list data. RecyclerView implementation is more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you get this error is that listview is not found by id. It seems like your adapter is first initialized from another activity, which is the real context for your layout with listview. There are two ways of solving this:
1) You should initialize your listview in update class through

```
ListView listView = context.findViewById(R.id.faclistview)
```

2) You can move your CallAdapter into actual context activity for your adapter

**UPDATE**
try that:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) ((ActivityWhereAdapterIsForstInitialized) context).findViewById(R.id.faclistview)
```

Comment: Moving the `CallAdapter()` into adapter class does not work. Same error. And your first solution is not in right format. It gives error too.

Comment: What is the error for the first solution? And you should not move CallAdapter into adapter class. You should have moved it into the activity class, which is the activity for the layout with the listview. The problem is that the listView in UpdateSupervitionActivity is not found. You can either extract the listview from transfered context, or move the actual method of reinitializing the adapter into the class where it is first initialized

Comment: Your first solution is not clear to me. There is no findViewById for context.

Comment: ListView listView = (ListView) ((YourRealActivityName) context).findViewById(R.id.faclistview)